# click to increase number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to increasing 100 each time when I clicked ? Any mistake I have make ? Please tell me thanks

```js
$(".label").click(function () {
        var number = 100;
        number++;
        $(".shownumber").text(number);

    });
```

```css
.label{
  width:auto;
  }
.label:hover{
  background:#ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label">click me</label>
<div class="shownumber">100</div>
```

Comment: the `number` variable should be declared outside the scope of the click event.

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous as to whether you want to add 1 or 100, but in any case, you can always add directly to the text value (converted to an integer). I am typically against using global vars for anything, as they do not scale (i.e. to multiple elements).

`text` allows you to supply a function, which will return the new text for the element:

```
$(".label").click(function () {
    $(".shownumber").text(function(){return ~~$(this).text() + 1}); // or 100!
});
```

Note: `~~` is a handy (and fast) shortcut conversion from string to integer.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/yuqr1p58/4/

With this approach you can support multiple elements, using some form of ownership arrangement. This one uses a containing `div` and `closest` and supports any number of these controls. This simply would not work using a global var.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/yuqr1p58/5/

Answer (score 1):

You were in the right path, but you have to **move** `var number = 100;` **outside the scope** of `click` function like below. Also you have to use `number += 100;`, to increment by `100`, instead of `number++` which just increment by 1.

```
var number = 100;
$(".label").click(function () {
   number += 100;
   $(".shownumber").text(number);
});
```

```js
var number = 100;
$(".label").click(function () {
   number += 100;
   $(".shownumber").text(number);
});
```

```css
.label{
     width:auto;
 }
.label:hover{
     background:#ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label">click me</label>
<div class="shownumber">100</div>
```

---

If you want to keep `number++` you can multiply `number` by `100` before insterting in page (`.text(number*100)`).

```js
var number = 1;
$(".label").click(function () {
   number++;
   $(".shownumber").text(number*100);
});
```

```css
.label{
     width:auto;
 }
.label:hover{
     background:#ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label">click me</label>
<div class="shownumber">100</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just ned to move the var num outside the scope of the click .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var number = 100;
$(".label").click(function() {

        number++;
        $(".shownumber").text(number);

    });
});
```

Comment: oopss..sorry ..hav made the changes

Comment: Hmm..  it is not clear whether he wants to add it by 100 or 1

Comment: Actually I have to agree with you now. The question is ambiguous. -1 removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var number = 100;
    $(".label").click(function () {

                number += 100;
                $(".shownumber").text(number);

            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuqr1p58/6/

Comment: Try clicking more than once. -1 for repeating original mistake.

Comment: I noticed. -1 removed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".label").click(function () {
    var number = 100;
    var oriNum= parseInt($(".shownumber").text())+number;
    $(".shownumber").text(oriNum);

});
```

[**Demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/yuqr1p58/1/)

with single line of Code

```
$(".label").click(function () {
    $(".shownumber").text( parseInt($(".shownumber").text())+100);
});
```

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/yuqr1p58/3/)

Comment: When supplying a completely different way of doing the task, best to explain to the OP "why" you did it that way :) (also that can be reduced to a single line using text with a function.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant (see my own answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var number = 100;
```

$(".label").click(function () {

```
    number += 100;
    $(".shownumber").text(number);

});
```